# What is the best way to write a setter for RealmList taking in an ArrayList?

Tags: android, realm

Say I have `RealmList<ObjectExtendsRealmObject> list;`

I want to have a setter for this that takes in `ArrayList` as a param. How do I update the objects in `RealmList` with this ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

I assume something like

```
public void setList(ArrayList<ObjectExtendsRealmObject> list) {
    if(this.list == null) {
        this.list = new RealmList<>(list);
    } else {
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: this.list = list does not work because RealmList != ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used below method to convert my **ArrayList** to **RealmList**.

```
public void setList(ArrayList<YourModel> list) {
  RealmList<YourModel> realmList=new RealmList<YouModel>(list.toArray(new YouModel[list.size()]));
}
```

this method is working perfect for me hope this will work for you.If you face any issue please let me know